# Can I use google auth inside facebook app

Tags: facebook, authentication

I want to use google authentication for web inside facebook application. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe so. Facebook would rather you use their own authentication/OAuth methods. You would need a user to log in with Facebook to do anything useful, anyways.

There is a way to hack the new Facebook comment system for Google authorization, but I don't know how long that will last. [(Source)](http://techcrunch.com/2011/03/07/facebook-comments-twitter-google-openid/)